# How to get a model using a variable in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to get the data by assigning the Model name to a variable like this?

I would like to retrieve data using the dynamic model name passed in as a parameter.

```rb
#Test is the model name
model_name = "Test"
model_name.all
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used constantize over string to retrieve data from model.

Let say "User" is my model name then I can retrive all users as below.

```
"User".constantize.all
```

This will return all user to me.

In your case

```
"Test".constantize.all
```

If you are not sure input string will not be camel case then you can use as below.

```
"Test".classify.constantize.all
```

For reference -

[constantize](https://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize)

[classify](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/classify)